# Giving an Enum static properties

Tags: c#, properties, static, enums

I had originally written my solution using an enum:

```
enum Speicies {
     monosiga,
     leidyi,
     queelslandica,
     hydra
};
```

But then I wanted to add constant properties to each of the enum options. i.e.

```
Speicies myOrganism = monosiga;
Console.writeLine(myOrganism.database);
Console.writeLine(myOrganism.class);
//Output: 
// c:\monosigadb.fasta
// Choanoflagellatea
```

This would imply that I should use a static class where I could use literals for the database and class variables for each species.

However, I wanted to retain the ability to have a Species object.

What would be the approach to this type of "advance enum"?

Comment: Maybe an interface `ISpecies` and several concrete class implementations of it?

Comment: You can use the `Description` attribute, or create additional attributes for your own purposes. See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paulwhit/archive/2008/03/31/use-the-descriptionattribute-with-an-enum-to-display-status-messages.aspx) for some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's what I was getting at:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<ISpecies> species = new List<ISpecies>();
        species.Add(new Cat());
        species.Add(new Dog());

        foreach (var specie in species)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(specie.ClassProp);
            Console.WriteLine(specie.DatabaseProp);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }

    public interface ISpecies
    {
        string ClassProp { get; }
        string DatabaseProp { get; }
    }

    public class Cat : ISpecies
    {
        public string ClassProp { get { return "Cat Class Property"; } }
        public string DatabaseProp { get { return "Cat Database Propery"; } }
    }

    public class Dog : ISpecies
    {
        public string ClassProp { get { return "Dog Class Property"; } }
        public string DatabaseProp { get { return "Dog Database Propery"; } }
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I needed. I didn't think to use an interface. I've only just recently been introduced to them. I had tried earlier use an abstract parent species class with derived static child classes for each species, but this is definitely the right way to do it. Thank you!